# When I reload a page on browser document.readyState changes almost with 1 sec from interactive to complete (even though images are not loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, lazy-loading

I have this code

```
$(document).on('readystatechange', function (){
      debugger;
      if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        $('img').each(function() {
          console.log('image printed=" +this);
        }
      })
 })
```

It runs properly when I hit my localhost page for the 1st time, but if I reload the same page (i.e. try to access the same page again) document.readyState  changes almost with 1 second from interactive to complete (even though images are not loaded).

Not able to understand the issue, is it because of cache, if yes, how can I ensure that my above code runs only after all images have loaded (whether they are coming from browser cache or from backend)

Image tag is like this:
/abc.jpg" width="45" height="45">

Comment: you are looking for document.load instead of document.ready. There is a significant difference. The document.ready just waits for the dom nodes to be available. The document.load waits for the entire paint job to be complete, i.e. loading of images etc.

Comment: You added a `lazy-loading` tag, is there anything more we should know about the image link creation because this should normally work as intended.

Comment: yes, the images are being lazy-loaded, something like this: <img loading="lazy" src="abc.png"/>

Comment: Try include more portions of your code. Also, in case it's just a typo and not an actual part of the problem, fix `console.log('image printed=" +this);` to be `console.log('image printed=' +this);`.

Comment: This is not actual part of problem.

Comment: Are you using a plugin for lazy loading? This script should work unless the images are loaded asynchronously somehow. This probably won't be noticeable when you run it locally because of the fast data transmission compared to the internet. That's really all I can think of.

Comment: Try this to see if the images are _actually_ loaded: https://jsfiddle.net/z7sq9cue

Comment: Fast data transmission means? Can you explain?

Comment: Fast data transmission means? Can you explain? Will it fast transmission if db is not local?

Comment: I also had 1 doubt, when I run this logic in debug mode, it runs fine, but normal mode, it does not, can you tell why it could be happening?

Comment: With that I meant that the images will load incredibly fast when they are taken from your hard drive while it will take visibly longer to download them from the internet. Your last comment might have to do with the fact that putting `debugger;` into the code creates an error if you run it normally but I'm not sure what's going on. Maybe you can check the developer tool console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for logic to be executed *after* the paint job has finished, i.e. the loading of your images, then you are looking for the `window.onload` method as opposed to the `document.ready` method.

Why is that? There is a significant difference between the two. The `document.ready` method executes as soon as the *DOM Nodes are available*, as opposed to an actual graphical presentation being represented to the the user. The `window.onload` method waits for the browsers paint job to be complete, meaning that *all graphical presentations are available* for the user.

You will see this effect in form of alerts in my example below. I even put the `window.onload` method first so that you can see that it's not due to the order in which they are declared.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  alert('I fire after images have loaded');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     alert('I fire before images are loaded');             
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/616/200/200.jpg?hmac=QEzyEzU6nVn4d_vdALhsT9UAtTUEVhwrT-kM5ogBqKM" />
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/430/200/200.jpg?hmac=RbYQ27bVLRKt5ScfTYiQ_ePoVdo70X4eWg2KPc6JF0I" />
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/998/200/200.jpg?hmac=Vc80YaPx9n6ZScRmWn3BK9EpGBVjYYCDlXpsZfYCOPw" />
<img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/432/200/200.jpg?hmac=b4-kxXh_oTpvCBH9hueJurvHDdhy0eYNNba-mO9Q8bU" />
```

Comment: They're not using `document.ready` but the `complete` value of `readyState` [which is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) just about the same as the `load` event.

Comment: I have tried using window.onload, but it works in the same way, images are loaded after executing the code section. And your snippet also only loads the 1st image before showing onload alert text.

Comment: @Anushka this isn't the case for me. The whole point of `window.onload` is to wait for the ENTIRE paint job to be done. It won't fire when only 1 image is loaded. It needs all of them to be loaded. This is also the behavior I see when running this code.

Comment: hmm, and should it behave same way if I re-run couple of times?

Comment: @Anushka yes, it should.

Comment: Ok. I also had 1 doubt, sometimes when I run this logic in debug mode, it runs fine, but normal mode, it does not, can you tell why it could be happening?

Comment: @Anushka Not sure about that, it'd need further investigation, which I cannot do with the current code base that's available.